# Каким образом отправлять JWT токен при авторизации на сервер?

Tags: javascript, jquery, token, jwt

Есть JWT токен, в документации сказано (https://jwt.io/introduction/) что для авторизации нужно отправлять

```html
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

в виде заголовка авторизации, но куда отправлять и каким способом? И что такое заголовок авторизации и как с ним работать на js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавляете в заголовоки запроса

```
var token = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c';
var url = 'https://exemple.com';
```

### fetch

```
fetch(url, { 
   method: 'POST', 
   headers: new Headers({
     'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   }), 
   body: { /* some data */ }
 });
```

### XMLHttpRequest

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.send(/* some data */);
```

### jQuery

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url
    data: { /* some data */ },
    contentType: 'application/json',           
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Bearer '+ token);
    }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, а это работает с обычным ajax из jquery?

Comment: @aSpectro да конечно, ajax из jQuery под капотом использует XMLHttpRequest, сейчас в пример добалю

Comment: Заголовки вроде отправляются, но я получаю ошибку "response for preflight does not have http ok status" я так понял это связано с cross-origin, не подскажите это проблема на клиенте или на сервере?

Comment: @aSpectro это браузер шлет `OPTIONS` запрос на сервер, а сервер должен подтвердить с каких доменов он может принимать запросы. У меня очень поверхностные знания по беку, можете для начала разрешить всем, добавить в заголовки ответа `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать

Comment: Почему надо добавлять `bearer ` перед токеном, а не просто токен отправить?

Comment: @doox911 Можете реализовать как Вам будет удобно, Bearer это схема авторизации на OAuth.