# Отправка запросов с параметром токена

Tags: javascript, api, rest, axios, token

Сразу хочу сказать, что в вопросе авторизации я пока полный ноль.

Ситуация такая. Я отправляю на сервер логин и пароль, сервер мне возвращает токен. И я так понимаю, что при каждом следующем обращении к серверу, тот должен проверять наличие токена.

Вот мне пришел токен. Куда мне его записывать? Я общаюсь с сервером по REST с помощью axios. Теперь я должен в свойствах аксиоса где-то в headers указать этот токен? Либо мне в мета-тегах его где-то указывать?

PS
Смотрю сваггер, там, к примеру, есть эндпоинт гет запроса http://0.0.0.0/api/getsomething?token=tokenstring

Но я сомневаюсь, что я в параметрах гет запроса в таком виде должен передавать токен

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/881836/256824

Answer (score 0):

Записывай токен куда-нить типа LocalStorage. При передачи axios-запроса добавляй заголовок с токеном, полученным из хранилища.